# Can Universal Windows Platform be used to develop windows software and not app

Tags: windows, uwp, software-distribution

I wished to develop a specialized software and NOT an app, which will be deployed at a few customer sites ultimately and ***not to be posted on Microsoft Store***. Can I use **Universal Windows Platform** for it? I did some research and the [official documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp) says -

> The Universal Windows Platform (UWP) **is the app platform** for Windows 10. You can develop apps for UWP with just one API set, one app package, and one store to reach all Windows 10 devices – PC, tablet, phone, Xbox, HoloLens, Surface Hub and more.

We want to develop a specialized software, with all its installers / DLLs / binaries etc etc which we will ship to a few customers and install at their PCs. So, my question is - Can we use Universal Windows Platform for developing such a software? Or if it be used only for app development, which ultimately needs to be loaded on the Microsoft Store for disbursement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP apps do not have to be distributed via public Microsoft Store. You can distribute the apps [via sideloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) and alternatively via [Microsoft Store for Business](https://www.petri.com/app-management-using-microsoft-store-business) which is a company-specific view into Microsoft Store, where you can publish internal apps.

Furthermore, you can package existing Desktop apps as UWP apps including their installers with the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root), which is useful when your app includes functionality, which is unavailable in pure UWP apps.

The main advantage of using UWP especially in conjunction with Microsoft Store for Business is simpler deployment and easier install and update lifecycle, however it might not suit you in complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to go about this (of a couple more)
 1. You can distribute the appx as you would an exe and have the client use side loading to install it on whatever machine is needed.
 2. you can release it in the [Microsoft Store for Business or Microsoft Store for Education](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store)